# PHP function returning reference conflicts with PHPCodeSniffer in custom WordPress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, phpcodesniffer

I tried the following code in my custom WordPress plugin:

```
function &test() {
  $a = 1;
  return $a;
}
```

This results in a codesniffer error:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
FOUND 1 ERROR AFFECTING 1 LINE
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 5 | ERROR | [x] No space after opening parenthesis is prohibited
   |       |     (WordPress.WhiteSpace.ControlStructureSpacing.NoSpaceAfterOpenParenthesis)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PHPCBF CAN FIX THE 1 MARKED SNIFF VIOLATIONS AUTOMATICALLY
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How to fix? Show me working code, please.

Comment: How to fix? Show me working code, please!

Comment: The wordpress standard is not compatible with the PSR. I think you need special phpcs config for wordpress.

Comment: you have to choose which coding standard to adhere to and modify your phpcs.xml or phpcs configuration accordingly.

Comment: I use default WordPress phpcs config - https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/trunk/phpcs.xml.dist

Comment: Show me working code that meets WordPress phpcs standard, please

Comment: hmm, does this help? `function &test() { ` by simply adding a space after the opening parenthesis, or am i understanding this wrong?

Comment: Also, are you really, really, really certain you need to return a reference? I've written a lot of PHP code in my life, and a large chunk of it is WordPress, and I don't think I've ever had to return a reference. I've needed to accept them in arguments occasionally, but that's it. Not related to your problem, just checking.

Comment: @Adi I think it wants this `&test () { ... `